# SQL query to compare column values

Tags: sql, teradata

I have below pattern of data and need to write SQL to validate test scenarios as below. This is just a sample my table has millions of records and need sql to validate. Any help/suggestion would be really appreciated.

> 1. EFEC_FROM of RANK_ORDER 2= EFEC_2 of  RANK_ORDER=1
> 2. EFEC_FROM of RANK_ORDER 3= EFEC_2 of  RANK_ORDER=2
> 3. EFEC_FROM of RANK_ORDER 4= EFEC_2 of  RANK_ORDER=3

And the data:

```
S_KEY FLAG_1  FLAG_2    EFEC_FROM                   EFEC_2                     RANK_ORDER   
100   1       0         2019-02-28 15:04:00.000000  2019-02-28 15:13:00.006000  1
100   0       0         2019-02-28 15:13:00.006000  2019-02-28 15:19:00.011000  2
100   0       0         2019-02-28 15:19:00.011000  2019-02-28 15:20:00.014000  3
100   0       1         2019-02-28 15:20:00.014000  2099-12-31 00:00:00.000000  4
```

Comment: you can use lead and lag function to get after/before row columns https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/amp/

Answer (score 0):

To find out what rows do not pass your validation rule you can use the `LAG()` or `LEAD()` functions, as in:

```
with 
x as (
  select
    s_key, flag_1, flag_2, efec_from, efec_2, rank_order,
    lag(efec_2 order by rank_order) prev_efec_2
from my_table
)
select *
from x
where efec_from <> prev_efec_2
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to validate running query as , SELECT * FROM ( SELECT s_key, flag_1, flag_2, efec_from, efec_2, COALESE(MIN(efec_from) OVER (PARTITION BY s_key ORDER BY rank_order asc), TIMESTAMP '2099-12-31 00:00:00') as NEXT_efec_from FROM table) WHERE efec_2 <> next_efec_from;

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use the LAG/LEAD functions to get information from the previous or next row in a data set.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT s_key,
       flag_1,
       flag_2,
       efec_from,
       efec_2,
       rank_order
       NVL (   LEAD (efec_from, 1)
               OVER (PARTITION BY s_key 
                         ORDER BY rank_order),
               '2099-12-31') AS next_efec_2
  FROM table)
WHERE efec_2 <> next_efec_from
```

Additional source for LAG/LEAD information: https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/NbZIb7BVEkYT9tMbXxOuog

Comment: Thank you. I was able to validate running query as , SELECT * FROM (
SELECT s_key,
       flag_1,
       flag_2,
       efec_from,
       efec_2,
       COALESE(MIN(efec_from)
       OVER (PARTITION BY s_key
                 ORDER BY rank_order asc), TIMESTAMP '2099-12-31 00:00:00') as NEXT_efec_from
               
  FROM table)
WHERE efec_2 <> next_efec_from;